# Glassfish server: How to get name of application deployment from inside glassfish application?

Tags: java, glassfish, jruby

I'm running jruby + java inside glassfish application container. 
I wonder if there is a way to get the name of application deployment from inside glassfish application. (appl is deployed using asadmin deploy --name  ...)

In other words, I'm looking for a way for an application (java or ruby code running) to know under which name it has been deployed.

Or maybe it there some other way to detect what deployment command was used to deploy the application from inside the application.

Answer (score 2):

> String anmae = (String) initialContext.lookup("java:app/AppName");

see http://javahowto.blogspot.nl/2009/12/how-to-get-module-name-and-app-name.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the command `asadmin list-applications` ? it will show you what applications have been deployed to the server. You can also check from the admin console (usually at localhost:4848 ) and click on the List-Applications from there.

Comment: Actually, I'm looking for a way for an application (java or ruby code running) to know under which name it has been deployed.